# How to set stripe style background in nativescript

Tags: android, css, nativescript

I want to draw a column with stripe style background in nativescript, and notice that linear-gradient is supported since nativescript4.0.
so i try following codes on android:

html:

```
<StackLayout class="equalizer" height="200"></StackLayout>
```

css:

```
.equalizer {   
    width:24;   
    background: linear-gradient(to top, white 50%, black);   
    background-size:100% 40;   
    background-repeat: repeat-y;   
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 1
}
```

Actually, the background expands to the whole StackLayout. The background-size & background-repeat takes no effect. 
What should i do if i want a stripe style background?

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=7I1s1W

Comment: can you please create a playground demo?

Comment: Of course, i have updated the question.

Comment: `background-size` is not working with linear gradient. you should open an issue for it.

Comment: Thanks  bhavin jalodara, i have recorded this issue in https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6053